# CSS background image not showing properly

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to put a post separator in my theme. I am using an image as separator. But the image is not showing up. Here is the code:

In index.php I have included (just before the ending of the loop):

```
<?php
    if (($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count)) {
        echo '<div class="post-item-divider">&nbsp Post Divider</div>';
    }
?>
```

The CSS:

```
.post-item-divider {
    background-image: url("/images/capture.png");
    height: 50px;
    line-height:1px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

But the image is not showing. However the text: "Post Divider" inside the div appears. I tried to replace the image url with an url from web it works fine.

Comment: If you can change the URL to something different then your code is fine.  The problem is likely that the filepath is incorrect.  Spelled wrong, or something.

Comment: make sure the url is correct...

Comment: If you set width to an actual pixel amount, do you see anything? It could be getting 100% width of 0px. Otherwise I would say it's the way you're trying to access the photo, wrong path

Comment: its working. Problem with the relative path of url. It should have been: images/capture.png

Comment: Try replacing `background-image: url("/images/capture.png");` with `background-image: url("images/capture.png");`

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code, I guess you are using wordpress. Anyway make sure that you are given right path for image.

If the remote URL is working fine with this code, I am sure url is wrong. Ensure the image is available in the mentioned path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the relative path of url. It should have been: images/capture.png.

I could not delete the question as it was already answered by others.

Answer (score -1):

It means that your css property: 
background-image: url("/images/capture.png");
path is incorrect replace it with 
background-image: url("../images/capture.png");
try that by firebug or inspect it.

Comment: While I agree that the url is relative to the source of the style sheet, testing it in your browser wouldn't help you much. Setting a relative url in firebug/codeinspector only works if the resource is already loaded (at least in my experience).